# Creating IAM users with Ansible - getting the CLI credentials

Tags: ansible

I am create usernames with the `iam` module, and I am using the `access_key_state: create` option.

However, I want my playbook to output the **Access Key** and the **Secret Access Key** for each user.

playbook.yml:

```
---
- name: "Starting the tasks: Creates IAM Policy, group, Role and User"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars_files:
    - vars/aws-credentials.yml

  tasks:

  - include: tasks/create-user.yml
    tags: user

  - include: tasks/create-group.yml
    tags: group
```

tasks/create-user.yml:

```
---
  # Create the IAM users with Console and API access
- name: Create new IAM users with API keys and console access
  iam:
    iam_type: user
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    password: "{{ lookup('password', 'passwordfile chars=ascii_letters') }}"
    access_key_state: create
    update_password: on_create
  no_log: true
  register: newusers
  loop:
    - johna
    - mariab
    - carlosc

- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ credentials.results }}"
```

The debug message `"{{ credentials.results }}"` gives me the Access Key, but not the Secret Access Key:

```
{
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "created_keys": [],
            "failed": false,
            "groups": null,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "access_key_ids": null,
                    "access_key_state": "create",
                    "aws_access_key": null,
                    "aws_secret_key": null,
                    "debug_botocore_endpoint_logs": false,
                    "ec2_url": null,
                    "groups": null,
                    "iam_type": "user",
                    "key_count": 1,
                    "name": "carol.v",
                    "new_name": null,
                    "new_path": null,
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "path": "/",
                    "profile": null,
                    "region": null,
                    "security_token": null,
                    "state": "present",
                    "trust_policy": null,
                    "trust_policy_filepath": null,
                    "update_password": "always",
                    "validate_certs": true
                }
            },
            "item": "carlosc",
            "keys": {
                "AK_________FV": "Active"
            },
            "user_meta": {
                "access_keys": [
                    {
                        "access_key_id": "AK_________FV",
                        "status": "Active"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "user_name": "carlosc"
        }
```

How to get the **Secret Access Key** for each user?

**Update 09 May 2020**: For [further reference](https://github.com/lpossamai/ansible-iam-cli-keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news; it appears they are purposefully throwing the `secret_access_key` in the trash: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.7/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/iam.py#L238-L241

It appears the only way around that is to set `key_count: 0` in your `iam:` and then use `awscli` or a custom ansible module to make that same `iam.create_access_key` call and *preserve* the result

```yaml
- name: create access key for {{ item }}
  command: aws iam create-access-key --user-name {{ item }}
  environment:
    AWS_REGION: '{{ the_region_goes_here }}'
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '{{ whatever_you_called_your_access_key }}'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '{{ your_aws_secret_access_key_name_here }}'
  register: user_keys
  with_items:
  - johna
  - mariab
  - carlosc
```

Feel free to file an issue, although you'll likely have to file it against the new [`amazon.aws` collection](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/issues) since that iam.py is no longer present in the `devel` branch

Comment: That's too bad! Would you have an example of how to achieve that using Ansible, please?

Comment: Sure, I didn't think the description was so opaque, but I updated the answer to include the skeleton of such a task

Answer (score 1):

You can use `community.aws.iam`:

```yaml
- name: Create IAM User with API keys
  community.aws.iam:
    iam_type: user
    name: some_dummy_user
    state: present
    access_key_state: create
  register: new_user
- debug:
    var: new_user
```

You'll be able to get your access and secret keys at:

- `new_user.user_meta.access_keys[0].access_key_id`
- `new_user.user_meta.access_keys[0].secret_access_key`

I have mine getting loaded into Secrets Manager and will eventually have them rotated with a lambda function.